# What file formats does CUPS support?

Tags: cups

What is the complete list of file formats that CUPS supports?  (i. e. what file types can I feed to `lpr` directly without having to convert them first?)

I have been searching for the answer and haven't found anything specific.  The best I've been able to find is "[CUPS understands many different types of files directly, including text, PostScript, PDF, and image files.](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html)"  But this is still fairly vague; in particular, what image file formats does it accept?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what filters are installed. (And no, I don't know how to find that out, but digging around `cupsfilter` should help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUPS uses a [MIME database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS#MIME_databases) to determine which file conversions it can can perform.

The database is composed of `*.convs` and `*.types` files.
Both of these have man pages:

- https://www.cups.org/doc/man-mime.convs.html
- https://www.cups.org/doc/man-mime.types.html

The [cupsd man page](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-cupsd.html) lists the locations of these files as:

- `/usr/share/cups/mime/mime.convs`
- `/usr/share/cups/mime/mime.types`

There are typically additional *.convs and *.types files in `/usr/share/cups/mime/`, and cupsd uses these as well.

On my Slackware 14.2 system, I get the following:

```
$ grep -h "^[^#]" /usr/share/cups/mime/*.convs | sort
application/msword  text/vnd.cups-brf   30  texttobrf
application/octet-stream    application/vnd.cups-raw    0   -
application/pdf     application/vnd.cups-pdf        66  pdftopdf
application/pdf     text/vnd.cups-brf   100 texttobrf
application/pdf image/tiff      80       pstotiff
application/postscript      application/vnd.cups-postscript 66  pstops
application/postscript  application/pdf             0   pstopdf
application/postscript  image/tiff      80       pstotiff
application/rtf     text/vnd.cups-brf   30  texttobrf
application/vnd.adobe-reader-postscript application/vnd.cups-postscript 66  pstops
application/vnd.cups-pdf    application/vnd.cups-postscript 100 pdftops
application/vnd.cups-pdf    application/vnd.cups-raster 100 pdftoraster
application/vnd.cups-pdf    application/vnd.cups-raster 99  gstoraster
application/vnd.cups-pdf image/tiff 80 pstotiff
application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner application/pdf         32  bannertopdf
application/vnd.cups-postscript application/vnd.cups-raster 175 gstoraster
application/vnd.cups-postscript image/tiff 80 pstotiff
application/vnd.cups-raster image/pwg-raster        100 rastertopwg
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document text/vnd.cups-brf   30  texttobrf
application/x-cshell        text/plain          100 -
application/x-cshell    application/pdf             32  texttopdf
application/x-csource       text/plain          100 -
application/x-csource   application/pdf             32  texttopdf
application/x-perl      text/plain          100 -
application/x-perl  application/pdf             32  texttopdf
application/x-shell     text/plain          100 -
application/x-shell application/pdf             32  texttopdf
application/xhtml   text/vnd.cups-brf   10  texttobrf
application/xml     text/vnd.cups-brf   10  texttobrf
image/gif           application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/gif       application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/gif       image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/gif       image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/jpeg          application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/jpeg      application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/jpeg      image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/jpeg      image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/pcx       image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/pcx       image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/png           application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/png       application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/png       image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/png       image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/pwg-raster    application/pdf             32  rastertopdf
image/svg       image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/svg       image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/tiff          application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/tiff      application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/tiff      image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/tiff      image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/urf       application/pdf             0   urftopdf
image/vnd.microsoft.icon    image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/vnd.microsoft.icon    image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-bitmap          application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-bitmap      application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-ms-bmp      image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-ms-bmp      image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-photocd         application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-photocd     application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-portable-anymap     application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-portable-anymap application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-portable-anymap image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-portable-anymap image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-portable-bitmap     application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-portable-bitmap application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-portable-bitmap image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-portable-bitmap image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-portable-graymap    application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-portable-graymap    image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-portable-graymap    image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-portable-graymap application/vnd.cups-pdf       65  imagetopdf
image/x-portable-pixmap     application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-portable-pixmap application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-portable-pixmap image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-portable-pixmap image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-sgi-rgb         application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-sgi-rgb     application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-sun-raster      application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-sun-raster  application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-xbitmap         application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-xbitmap     application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-xbitmap     image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-xbitmap     image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-xpixmap         application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster
image/x-xpixmap     application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-xpixmap     image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-xpixmap     image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
image/x-xwindowdump application/vnd.cups-pdf        65  imagetopdf
image/x-xwindowdump image/vnd.cups-brf  70  imagetobrf
image/x-xwindowdump image/vnd.cups-ubrl 70  imagetoubrl
text/css            text/plain          100 -
text/html           text/plain          100 -
text/html       application/pdf             32  texttopdf
text/html       text/vnd.cups-brf   10  texttobrf
text/plain      application/pdf             32  texttopdf
text/plain      text/vnd.cups-brf   0   texttobrf
text/rtf        text/vnd.cups-brf   30  texttobrf
```

You can also see which filters will be used by a conversion by calling `cupsfilter` directly with a file and the `--list-filters` option (which will not print the file):

```
$ cupsfilter --list-filters foo.png
imagetoraster
rastertopwg
rastertopdf
```

(Note: I have a default printer set via `lpoptions`, so I didn't have to supply the printer name.  If you do have to, you can pass the printer name to `cupsfilter` with the `-d` option.)